# VMWare Fusion on Mac w/ Ubuntu - Setting up shared LAMP Environment

Tags: ubuntu, php, mac, lamp, development

I recently purchased a Mac and installed VMware Fusion and Ubuntu.  I've setup LAMP on Ubuntu and setup a mirrored folder between the mac and ubuntu.

I want to be able to do my development on the Mac with the projects folder in the mirrored folder.  I'd like to be able to access the sites (being run on the VM Ubuntu), via browser on the Mac-side as well.

How do I setup my hosts to recognize the sites setup on Ubuntu?  Basically, I think I have things setup properly, but where do I go from here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting you right and LAMP is already running, the only thing that must be set up is a network card in fusion. It can be configured as Host-Only, NAT or Bridged depending on your needs beside your dev. If this is done, just type the IP of your Ubuntu into the addressbar of any browser on the mac.

If you need to access it over names just edit your Macs hosts file. Or use a tool I wrote called "[ManageDSCL](http://www.pulsemedia.de/software/opensource/managedscl)" it's an applescript wraping OSX' "Directory Service command line utility".